# Unity3D. Мелькание картинки

Tags: c#, canvas, unity3d, transform

В общем проблема такая. Идет себе игра и вдруг мелькает какая то картинка (эта картинка уже назначена какому то объекту, просто она мелькает на полэкрана или на весь экран) Иногда сразу несколько картинок мелькает, скриншот не скину, потому что время этого мелькания очень маленькое. Если хоть какие то догадки есть, прошу напишите, я весь интернет облазил, не знаю что делать.

Иерархия обектов такая: Есть большой canvas, с самописным скриптом, реализующим многоэкранный вид (элементарная манипуляция положением камеры). Естественно все игровые объекты у меня внутри этого канваса (ну кроме камеры и eventSystem).

Вот небольшой отрывок кода одного из скриптов:

```
GameObject copy = Instantiate<GameObject>(gameObject);
Destroy(copy.GetComponent<ThisScript>());
copy.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
```

(я делаю копию этого же обекта и удаляю в нем этот скрипт, для избежания рекурсии).
Так вот, я убрал "false" в методе setParent, практически все глюки пропали (всё равно ловил мелькания, но значительно реже и меньше, по крайней мере объекты рядом с этим уже перестали мелькать)

Ещё в этом ж скрипте потом используется постоянное движение обеъкта, через манипуляцию localPosition, если установить position (не local), глюки вроде тоже пропадают. Даже элементарно если повыключать некоторые объекты глюк пропадает (собственно и описываю некоторые особенности этих объектов), хотя и то я не уверен, может он просто стал намного реже появляется.

Ах да, у меня есть эта же весия игры, только кавасов было много, для текста, остальное только через Sprite Renderer, таких проблем с мельканием уже не было. Но всё это чуть медленее работает и дольше грузится, плюс свою обработка прикосновений, вместо стандартной, поэтому хочется всё же сдалть это одним кавасом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем чудом узнал что за проблема. Это банальный глюк Unity. Ребята где то там налажали. Этот глюк описан в списке их багов. Обещают исправить в следующей версии юнити. А пока что создаем дефолтный материал UI - default, и назначаем его на все Image, RawImage, Text. Эй... 5 дней на это потратил, думал что же я сделал не так...